# Variable assignment when reading from file using cat

Tags: bash, file, cat

I have a txt file that is in the format below:

```
name1    path/to/some/directory
name2    path/to/some/other/directory
name3    path/to/some/directory
name4    path/to/some/other/directory 
...
```

Here is the code I have written to read this file line by line:

```
NUM=1
for line in $(cat /path/to/my/file.txt);  do
if [ $((NUM%2)) -eq 1 ]
then 
    name= $line #this line does not work
    echo $line #while this line works just fine

else 
    sudo tar -cf /desired/path/$name.tar $line
fi
NUM=$((NUM+1))
done
```

This code actually reads file word by word, and it alternates between *then* and *else* of *if* statement. Once it assigns a value it has read to variable name (*then* part inside *if*), then it uses that variable in command that is performed in *else* part of *if*. (This is how I expect it to work.)

The problem that arises is that variable assignment in *then* part of *if* seems not to work, it sees word it has just read as command, and doesn't assign its value to variable. I tried to echo it and it works just fine.

Why `name= $line` variable assignment is not working?

Thank you for any suggestions, comments or answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignments in bash require no space around `=`.

Hence, you need to say:

```
name="$line"
     ^     ^
     quotes!
```

This happens because anything happening after the declaration is considered a command. See for example this, that tries to define `r` to `2` and then `echo 1` is executed:

```
$ r=2 echo 1
1
```

This is why it is also a good thing to quote the declaration: `name="$line"`.

---

Regarding the parsing and definition of variables  of the file, you can maybe use this approach:

```
declare $('s/\s\+/="/; s/$/"/' a)
```

This replaces the spaces in between the first and second word by `="` and the end of line with `"`. This way, `name /path/` gets converted into `name="/path/"`. By using `declare`, this command gets executed and makes variables be ready for use.

```
$ cat a
name1 aa
name2 rr
name5 hello
$ sed 's/\s\+/="/; s/$/"/' a
name1="aa"
name2="rr"
name5="hello"
$ declare $('s/\s\+/="/; s/$/"/' a)
```

So now you have the variables ready to use:

```
$ echo "$name5"
hello
```

And finally, note that this is equivalent (and better) than `for line in $(cat /path/to/my/file.txt)`:

```
while IFS= read -r val1 val2 ...
do
    ... things ...
 done < /path/to/my/file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, with clear and concrete explanations... I changed my code and learn new things... you helped :)